# How do I fix issues resolving internet on ubuntu 20.04 for WSL 2

Tags: 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am getting the following errors when trying to run `apt-get update` and install a needed package to my WSL 2 Ubuntu 20.04 instance:

```
<redacted>:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
<redacted>:~$ sudo apt install unzip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  zip
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  unzip
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 169 kB of archives.
After this operation, 593 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 unzip amd64 6.0-25ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unzip/unzip_6.0-25ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Is there anything I can do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the system couldn't contact a DNS server that could resolve the domain names. Here are some fixes...

Temporarily, you can edit the `/etc/resolv.conf` file with the DNS server you'd like to use. For example, add the line `nameserver 8.8.8.8`, save the file and try again.

For a persistent DNS config, you may want to edit the `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` file. Uncomment the `DNS` and `FallbackDNS` lines by removing the `#` sign.

Now add your preferred DNS servers. The `FallbackDNS` line is optional anyway

```
DNS=8.8.8.8
FallbackDNS=8.8.4.4
```

Save the file and exit. Also, you may want to clear any cached queries. Use the command `systemd-resolve --flush-caches` or `resolvectl flush-caches`

Now DNS should work fine.

Comment: Just a heads-up that, unfortunately, most of this  is not applicable to and won't work under Ubuntu on WSL, which is what the question is about.

Comment: This did not work on WSL 2, the ubuntu instance still refuses to connect to the internet in any way at all.

Comment: I found this issue open on GitHub as well, check it out here https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5256

The fix is given by one JohnnyQuest1983, you may need to scroll through a bit to find it.